# High dimensional parametric skew distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

What are the best researched options for a parametric multivariate probability distribution that is able to be skewed, given curvature, and possibly even multiple modes? I have done some research into unified skew normal distributions and unified skew elliptical distributions, but the available research is very lean, and I've yet to find any method for actually estimating such distributions given data which is purported to follow it.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but note that SE explicitly discourages cross-posting. Please pick the site you prefer and delete the other question.

Comment: All right, I'll leave it here, even though I think it's a bit less active.

Comment: You're right that CV is less active than math.SE, but I suspect you're also right that this is a better fit. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here after a period of time, you can flag your Q & ask the moderators to migrate it to m.SE & give it another try.

Comment: what do you mean by 'unified distributions'?

Comment: The unified skew normal is a generalization of the skew normal distribution to high dimensions- I think it is an example of exactly what I am looking for, but it is a bit difficult to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a finite mixture of skew distributions or the flexible class of distributions proposed in the paper

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9469.2004.03_007.x/abstract